# .htaccess Prettifying URLS for PHP

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Urls by default**

`/courses/category?cat=skills`

`/courses/course?cat=skills&course=timekeeping`

I have been trying to get the above shortened down to be accessible at

**Desired**

`/courses/skills`

`/courses/skills/timekeeping`

Using the below works for when `cat` and `course` have variables

`RewriteRule ^courses/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /courses/course?cat=$1&course=$2 [L]`

I have tried adding `RewriteRule ^courses/([^/]*)$ /courses/category?cat=$1&course=$2 [L]` too but When I try access `/courses/skills` it comes up with:

**Internal Server Error**

NOTE: `.php` has been removed by using

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your complete .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^courses/([^/.]+)/?$ /courses/category?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^courses/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /courses/course?cat=$1&course=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^courses/([^/]*)$ /courses/category?cat=$1&course=$2 [L]
```

Here, `$2` means nothing, since you have not defined it.

Use this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^courses/([^/]*)$ /courses/category?cat=$1 [L]
```